# Insert into SQL and delete the record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I am processing a tag list into the `tblOffsite` database table and then need to delete from core table (`tblOnStock`). My primary key is the `tagID`. How do I use the processed `tagID`'s to delete from the core table?

Here is my code:

```
sc.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Steripack;User ID=remote;Password=0925Greg#");
sc.Open();

com.Connection = sc;
com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO tblOffsite (tagID, Hospital, Driver, datetime) SELECT tagID, Hospital, Driver, datetime FROM tblDelivery");

com.ExecuteNonQuery();
sc.Close();

sc.Open();
com.Connection = sc;
com.CommandText = ("DELETE FROM tblOnStock WHERE tagID = @tagID");
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
sc.Close();
```

Comment: add the @tagID parameter for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean whatever you have inserted in tblOffsite should be deleted from tblOnStock?

In that case your SQL to delete should be:

```
DELETE FROM tblOnStock WHERE tagID IN (SELECT tagID FROM tblDelivery)
```

Comment: Hi, now I need to check tblOnStock to verify the tagID's are actually in there first before deleting.... Perhaps an IF statement...

Comment: You won't really need it. If the tagIDs are not there then the delete statement will ignore that and not delete anything. It will not throw any error.